# how to close alert dialog from activity without user interaction?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In my Android application I have created a common class for handling general functions such as showing alert dialog, manipulation date functions. I show alert dialog just call a method by passing text message. My question is how to close the alert dialog programmatically which is in another class?

my code flow:

`UtillClass2` is a class which has `common methods` used in application.

```
public class UtillClass2 {
    public static void showAlert(Context context, String str) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.common_alert);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_button);
        TextView alerttxt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_text1);
        alerttxt.setText(str);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And I call the alert dialog from my `Activity` by calling like this

```
        UtillClass2.showAlert(QNowActivity.this, getResources()
                .getString(R.string.available_err));
```

My question is I want to close the alert dialog by programmatically from the activity ?

Comment: you should probably return the dialog because how are you going to get access to it after you create it?

Comment: can you please pass the applicationcontext to the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Creat a Global instance of your dialog instance like below :

```
private Dialog mDialog; // global class variable .
```

dismiss the dialog with `mDialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code, I thin it's helpful for you.

```
public class UtilDialog {
public final static int ALERT_DIALOG = 1;

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

public UtilDialog(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.message));
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            resources.getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

}

public void showDialog(String message, int dialogCode) {
    switch (dialogCode) {
    case ALERT_DIALOG:
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.show();
        break;
    }

}

public void dismissDialog(int dialogCode) {
    switch (dialogCode) {
    case ALERT_DIALOG:
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

and use this alert dialgon in another class

```
 UtilDialog utilDialog=new UtilDialog(this);

utilDialog.showDialog(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.all_fields),
                    UtilDialog.ALERT_DIALOG);
utilDialog.dismissDialog(UtilDialog.ALERT_DIALOG);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UtillClass2 {

Dialog dialog;

public static void showAlert(Context context, String str) {
    dialog = new Dialog(context,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.common_alert);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_button);
    TextView alerttxt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_text1);
    alerttxt.setText(str);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

public static void hideAlert()
{
    if(dialog != null)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you shew your dialog like this:

```
EnterPinDialog enterPinDialog = EnterPinDialog.newInstance(...);
enterPinDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), EnterPinDialog.TAG);
```

then you can close it like this:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(EnterPinDialog.TAG);
if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof EnterPinDialog) {
    EnterPinDialog enterPinDialog = (EnterPinDialog)fragment;
    enterPinDialog.dismiss();
    //enterPinDialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}
```